# Body format options for OpenRasta POST action

Tags: post, openrasta

Given the following code and config for OpenRasta :

```
ResourceSpace.Has.ResourcesOfType<Foo>()
    .AtUri("/foo/{fooID}")
    .And.AtUri("/foo")
    .HandledBy<FooHandler>()
    .AsJsonDataContract();

public OperationResult GetFoo(int fooID) { }

public OperationResult PostFoo(Foo foo) { }

public class Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

What is the correct format for the body of the request if I want to post to the PostFoo method on my FooHandler. Can it be json (i.e. the same format I would recieve from GetFoo) or should it be name-value pairs (e.g. ID=1&Name=FooManChu) ?

Do I need to set any additional headers in the post request such as content type ?

I am trying to get this working but I seem to be getting 415 errors when I try to do this ?

Comment: Ah. I seem to have answered my own question. Yes, it can be json and yes, apparently I do have to add  a Content-Type header of application/json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you send a Content-Type of application/json, that'll work. If you want to use key value pairs, using either multipart/form-data or application/x-www-form-urlencoded then that'll work too.

If you don't specify Content-Type, it defaults to application/octet-stream, for which you only have a mapping to Stream (and byte[]).